# Please restore "ethnicity" tag in this question

Tags: support, retagging

For this question, [When referring to races, should 'black' and 'white' be capitalized? (MLA)](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/81218/32436), please restore the "ethnicity" tag which a moderator removed.  As my answer shows, this question will be viewed and answered in different ways depending on the reader's racial identity and affinity.

(Should I have flagged the question instead of writing a Meta question?)

Answer (score 7):

I removed the [ethnicity](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ethnicity) tag because, as I noted in the edit summary, the question is

> not about "interacting with people of different ethnicities"

which is what the tag excerpt says the tag is for.

I also left a [comment](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/81218/when-referring-to-the-race-should-black-be-capitalized-mla#comment201094_81248) just now explaining why I *don't* think that the question is "answered in different ways depending on the reader's racial identity and affinity".

Comment: Please note, I also said "viewed" differently.

Comment: I looked at the definitions of the ethnicity and diversity tags.  Apparently the diversity tag is not as narrowly defined as the ethnicity tag is.  I have accordingly added the diversity tag to the referenced question.

Comment: @aparente001 I really don't think the diversity tag is appropriate either. I suggest asking on meta to see what the rest of the community thinks.

Comment: ff524 ........ Will do.

Answer (score 4):

In this case, meta is better than a flag since disagreements about edits are best resolved by the community and not by moderators acting unilaterally.

While it was a moderator who removed the tag, it wasn't "moderation", but rather just a user tidying up how they thought best. Had you put the tag back and the user, who happens to be a moderator, removed it again, another moderator would have stepped in and temporarily locked the post and asked on meta for help resolving the edit "war". By coming here first you prevent people feeling attacked and make life easier for the moderators.

As for the tag itself, I agree with this [answer](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3591/929) that it is not needed.